# Read microft project files (.mpp) with objective c / iphone sdk

Tags: php, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I want to extract data from a microsoft project file (.mpp) file and show the data on a UITableView . I searched everywhere but i could not find any solution for it. There are some apps on the app store that does the task but i could not find any way howa to achieve this .

Please provide me solution to this problem . Maybe proper solution here can also help other developers doing the same thing .

Thanks .

Comment: @ mark : FOr alternatives like doing the extraction on server and than send the data to the device via web services.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net). You could either use it on the server side as part of a Java or .Net application to process MPP files and pass back the contents to your mobile application, or you could use [XMLVM](http://xmlvm.org) to convert the MPXJ libraries to C and use them directly on the device. RoboVM may also allow you to take a similar approach by converting MPXJ's Java bytecode into a native library... I haven't researched this in as much depth so I'm not sure of RoboVM's capabilities in this area.